# How I can search keyword from text file/ sql file in c#.net which are not commented?

Tags: c#, sql

I have to search keywords from a .sql or .txt file. Those keywords should not be in comments.

e.g. if I want to search 2 keywords like "set rowcount" and "holdlock". I was able to find these in a file. But As per requirement. these should not be in comment. (not between /* */ or starts with //).

Can anyone give me an idea.

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    int s_start = FileDisplayArea.SelectionStart, startIndex = 0, index;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    while ((index = FileDisplayArea.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
    {
        NoOfOccurance[wordIndex] += 1;
        FileDisplayArea.Select(index, word.Length);
        FileDisplayArea.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
        startIndex = index + word.Length;
    }

    FileDisplayArea.SelectionStart = s_start;
    FileDisplayArea.SelectionLength = 0;
    FileDisplayArea.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    wordIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: Would the comments be the ONLY part of the comment (e.g. //set rowcount) or could there be other comment content before them (e.g. //hey, use set rowcount here)?

Comment: Thanks Chris.
It could be other contents before the comments like

/******** This is comment  Set Rowcount ******/

or 

// This is used for count SET ROWCOUNT

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? Number of occurrences of that phrase? If there is an occurrence of that phrase? Location of that phrase?

Comment: I want to show the keywords which are deprecated in new sql new versions. I have find the keywords from text /sql file.  I am grabbing all the keywords  like SET ROWCOUNT, HOLDLOCK but i need skip the keywords coming in comment sections of sql.

Comment: Okay, but **exactly** what do you need? The indexes of occurrences of those keywords?

Comment: Yes, I need the line number of that occurrences of keywords.

Comment: `while((string line = file.ReadLine()) != null) { ++lineNum; if(!line.StartsWith("//") && !line.StartsWith("/*")) { // print line num, do something with line, whatever } }` Of course, you can always find the index of where a comment starts if the comment is inline `line.indexOf("/*")...or...line.indexOf("//")` and then just read up to that index of the string, or split at that index, etc... Lot's of options here.

Comment: thanks lngenioushax, but if comment is in 3 lines like    /* comments starts ............................. 2nd line .............. */ comment ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys. I solved this by following logic.

```
    bool commentStarted = false, commentEnds = false;

foreach (string line in scriptAllLines)
                    {
                         if (line.Contains("/*"))
                        {
                            commentStarted = true;
                            commentEnds = false;
                        }
                        if (line.Contains("*/"))
                        {
                            commentEnds = true;
                            commentStarted = false;
                        }
}
```